# un listen to event while modify-interaction and reactivate on listen after

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm struggling again with the unByKey/ol.Observable stuff...

I got a event listener for creating popups.

```
var unByKeyPopup;
unByKeyPopup = map.on('click', function (evt) {
  ...
});
```

Then I have an modify interaction which is activated when a checkbox is set on true.

```
 function xyz() {
  ....

 $('#checkbox').on('click', function () {
  if(this.checked) {
    modifyVectorInteraction();
    $('#checkbox').un('click', unByKeyPopup);  //????? dont activate the Popup thing while the user is in modify interaction
  } if(!this.checked) {
    map.removeInteraction(modifyinteraction);  
    $('#checkbox').on('click', unByKeyPopup);  //????? ok, modify done, lets re-activate the Popup 
  }
  ...
 });
 ...
}
```

Well... this doenst work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Ok I have a workaround for the popop listener. I added to the layer a property to the layer:
`nopopup: true`
and have the following atm: 
`unByKeyPopup = map.on('click', function (evt) {
function (feature, layer) {
if (layer.get('nopopup') !== true) {
...
`

It works more or less, but more elegant would be the unByKey-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying with the wrong method, use [`unByKey`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#unByKey) instead:

```
map.unByKey(unByKeyPopup);
```

UPDATE:

Instead of:

```
unByKeyPopup = map.on('click', function (evt) {
  ...
});
```

Create a function that makes the job:

```
var popupFunction = function(evt){
    //...
};
```

And active/reactive it with:

```
unByKeyPopup = map.on('click', popupFunction);
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right. But how can I re-activate the Popup afterwards? Do I have to do this with ol.Observable ?

Comment: Hmmm. Ok that helped me  a lot. Thank you. I will try to understand why this way later.

Comment: Let me know if it is missing something.